# convert map to bson

Tags: go, mgo

```
type Player struct {
    id bson.ObjectId
    test map[int]int
}

func (this *Player) Id() bson.ObjectId {
    return this.id
}

func (this *Player) DbObj() bson.D {

    testBson := bson.D{}
    for k,v := range this.test {
        testBson = append(testBson, bson.M{"id":k, "v":v}) // compile error
    }
    return bson.D{
        {"_id",this.id},
        {"test", testBson},
    }
}
```

The bson document should be:

```
{'_id':ObjectId(xx),'test':[{'id':1,'v':1},..., {'id':2,'v':2}]}
```

But I don't know how to convert the map object to `[{'id':1,'v':1},..., {'id':2,'v':2}]`, bson.M is not the type DocElem which D contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Go slice to represent the BSON array:

```
func (this *Player) DbObj() bson.D {
    var testBson []bson.M
    for k,v := range this.test {
        testBson = append(testBson, bson.M{"id":k, "v":v}) 
    }
    return bson.D{
        {"_id",this.id},
        {"test", testBson},
    }
}
```